# Raster area (QGIS) problem explained

Tags: qgis, raster, area

I would like to know the area that each value in a raster has... The raster I have has values from 2-15 and I would like to know the area that each value is occupaying within my polygon... Thanks!

I vectorized and calculated the area using geometry columns but I find a problem when I add all of the calculated segments, they don't match the poligon's total area!

The fist picture is the resulting raster, I clipped my polygone out and then vectorized it (pic of de right)...

[image]

Comment: a sample of the erroneous result (print screen or something similar) would help a lot. Also are you performing your calculations in a valid CRS? WSG84 (epsg:4326) is not a very good choice because by definition the measurements are in degrees.

Comment: I am using UTM :)

Comment: you said the error is in the area measurements. we'll need to see them.

Comment: Yes, well tha's been analyzed using excel but I will try a couple of solutions I saw in other question responses

Comment: Can you post the differences in area? How did you get the total area in the raster btw?